# Shorter Regular expression to match 3 alphanumeric characters as well as $ and - followed by 000051-999999

Tags: regex

i came up with the below expression, which works but its very long and was wondering if there was a way to shorten it.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9&-]{3}[0]{4}[5][1-9]$|[a-zA-Z0-9&-]{3}[0]{4}[6-9]\d$|[a-zA-Z0-9&-]{3}[0]{3}[1-9]\d{2}$|[a-zA-Z0-9&-]{3}[0]{2}[1-9]\d{3}$|[a-zA-Z0-9&-]{3}[0][1-9]\d{4}$|[a-zA-Z0-9&-]{3}[1-9]\d{5}$
```

Any help would be appreciated

i tried replacing the `[a-zA-Z0-9&-]` with `(?!_)\w[&-]` but it's not much shorter

Comment: What is this supposed to match? Could you give some examples?

Comment: can you use extended regular expressions? (\w, \d, etc)

Comment: If you use the common `i` flag, you can already remove all `A-Z`.

Comment: *"as well as $ and -"*: then why do you allow `&` and not `$`?

Comment: So the first three characters can be digits? Like 999000051 and 999999999 are allowed inputs?

Comment: Gus's suggestion helps a lot. Also alter the logic for the numbers \d{4}5[1-9] | \d{4}[6-9]\d. I think that's about right - subject to typos.

Comment: Trivially, `[5]` matches exactly the same text as the much shorter `5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some things you can save on:

- `[0-9]` is `\d`
- `[a-zA-Z]` is `[a-z]` when you use the `i` flag
- Avoid repeating `[a-zA-Z0-9&-]{3}` by using parentheses for the part that *follows* this pattern
- Instead of (positively) matching all combinations between 000051 and 999999, allow all 6-digit sequences, but exclude the ones between 000000 and 000050 with a negative look-ahead.

That leads to this equivalent regex, provided you use the `i` flag:

```
^[a-z\d&-]{3}(?!0000(?:[0-4]|50))\d{6}$
```